# XML validation against XSD with javax.xml.validation.Validator: cannot resolve types come from 2nd XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd, saxparser, xml-validation

I am trying to write a method that validates XML against XSD.
In my case, I have multiple XSD files.

When I use tools like IntelliJ IDEA to generate a sample XML from my main XSD everything looks fine:  the sample XML is generated and looks as I expect. So I think that my XSD files are okay.

**This is my simplified main XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">

    <xsd:import schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" />

    <xsd:element name="Message">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="messageId" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element ref="ds:Signature" minOccurs="0" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="Id" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I downloaded and put the `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd` in the same directory with my XSD files.

**The error I get:**

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ds:Signature' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
```

**Java code:**

```
InputStream xsdStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schema/my.xsd");
// 1. InputStream xsdSignatureStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schema/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd");

Source[] sources = new StreamSource[1];
sources[0] = new StreamSource(xsdStream);
// 2. sources[1] = new StreamSource(xsdSignatureStream);

SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
// 3. schemaFactory.setResourceResolver(new ClasspathResourceResolver());
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(sources);

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

String xmlString = "...";
StringReader xmlStringReader = new StringReader(xmlString)
Source source = new StreamSource(xmlStringReader);
validator.validate(source);
```

So it seems that the `javax.xml.validation.Validator` does not see my 2nd XSD file. So  I tried to add it when I initialize the `javax.xml.validation.Schema` but it does not help (see commented lines 1. and 2.).

I also tried to create and add an external `ResourceResolver` (see commented line 3.), but it does not help.

*Comment:*
The streams I use are initialized properly, the file paths are good, I can read the content from streams and log it as strings.

What I miss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that when the schema document is loaded using `getResourceAsStream("schema/my.xsd");` it doesn't have a known base URI and therefore the relative URI `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd` doesn't resolve properly. Try setting a base URI (`systemId` property) on your `StreamSource` object.

Comment: Your comment helped me to understand better the issue I have so I accept it as a nice solution. But unfortunately, this brings another issue for me. It works if I execute my app as a single Spring-Boot app. But my WAR deploys to WebLogic and WebLogic makes magic with files: it puts resource files in a `_wl_cls_gen.jar`. And `javax.xml.transform.Source` not able to resolve this path, because `java.io.File` does not able to follow this path: `/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/DEV_DOMAIN/servers/ADMIN_SERVER/tmp/_WL_user/demo-0.1.0/g369dl/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/schema/main.xsd`

Answer (score 1):

I had same error:
`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ds:Signature' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.`

And wasted several hours trying to handle it somehow.
Try to remove from "xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" all content between:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

and

```
<schema
```

It's DOCTYPE definition in that place and my assumption, that parser can't handle it correctly.