# XML validation against XSDs when schema files locate in a WAR

Tags: java, xml, xsd, weblogic, saxparser

I am trying to validate XML against multiply XSD schemas.

The following code works like a charm if I execute my app as a simple Spring-Boot application:

```
// init
String[] xsdFileNames = ...
Source[] sources = new Source[xsdFileNames.length];

for (int i = 0; i < xsdFileNames.length; i++) {
    InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xsdFileNames[i]);
    String realPath = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(xsdFileNames[i]).getFile();

    StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(inputStream);
    streamSource.setSystemId(realPath );

    sources[i] = streamSource;
}

SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(sources);
validator = schema.newValidator();

// validate
String xmlString = ...
StringReader xmlStringReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
Source source = new StreamSource(xmlStringReader);
validator.validate(source);
```

The `systemId` of the `StreamSource` needs to be set otherwise the `SAXParser` can not see the XSD types come from the 2nd XSD. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60304496/xml-validation-against-xsd-with-javax-xml-validation-validator-cannot-resolve-t).

But unfortunately, my WAR needs to run in the Oracle WebLogic Server, and because WebLogic makes a trick with files from WAR the solution above does not work.

WebLogic packs resource files into a `_wl_cls_gen.jar`, and `javax.xml.transform.Source` does not able to resolve the path with this magic jar: `.../_wl_cls_gen.jar!/schema/main.xsd`.

Inside `javax.xml.transform.Source` there is a `java.io.File` and it not following this strange path.

This is the value of the `realPath` variable in case of Spring-Boot:

```
/home/xxx/dev/workspace/java/xxx/target/classes/schema/main.xsd
```

And in case of WebLogic:

```
/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/DEV_DOMAIN/servers/ADMIN_SERVER/tmp/_WL_user/demo-0.1.0/g369dl/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/schema/main.xsd
```

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Be careful with real-pathes pointing into compressed files (like *.war and *.jar). I know that this works in WebLogic, but it does not work in other application servers, e.g. Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using show-archived-real-path-enabled in weblogic.xml

> show-archived-real-path-enabled The show-archived-real-path-enabled
>   element specifies the behavior of getRealPath() for archived Web
>   applications.
>
> When set to true, getRealPath() returns the canonical path of the
>   resource files.
>
> If the show-archived-real-path-enabled element is set to false, the
>   servlet container will return the real path of files in archived Web
>   applications as null.
>
> The default value is false.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP611

Comment: One comment: if I want to use `getRealPath()` then I need to have `javax.servlet.ServletContext`. But it easy to autowire with Spring. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can load files from inside a *.war using the Classloader, e.g.

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/myfile.xsd");
```